# How to compare multi column by using rolling_apply in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare multi column of a Dataframe in Pandas with this condition.

```
current_row[col1] > current_row[col2] and previous_row[col1] < previous_row[col2]
```

e.g.

```
col1 col2
0    1
1    0
0    1
1    0
1    0   

output
NaN
True
False
True
False
```

I know that it should be use the function like this,

```
rolling_apply(df, 
              window=2, 
              func=lamda x: x[col1][0] > x[col2][0] and x[col1][-1] < x[col2][-1])
```